# Android - Load a progress bar while BROWSER loads a page (NO WEBVIEW)

Tags: android, browser, progress-bar

I`m making a simple app, just for fun, and at some point i want it to open a URl at the browser, doing it with

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Now, i want to show a progress bar loading while the browser loads the page, but the best i got was:

```
ProgressBar mProgress;
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
mProgress.setProgress(0);
mProgress.incrementProgressBy(1); // lots of times
mProgress.setProgress(100);
```

and this only takes time from the user, cute, but useless.

Any way of make the progress bar load while the page loads in background?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE - NO WEBVIEW

I`m aware that webview would be better, but the whole idea of the post is to know if it is possible a progressbar to load while waits for an outside aplication open in background.

Answer (score 0):

You could start the progressbar by making it visible, then download. Rather than just start a browser, though, I would load the page into a WebView. I would override the WebView and set a onPageFinished() listener within which I would stop the progressBar

Comment: I wanted to use a a webview at first, but i`m opening a faceapp, and as far as i saw, since october 2013 facebook kind block their apps from open on webviews.. so i droped this and i`m tryng through the browser, not the best way but still nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:text="loading web in WebView Client"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal">      
   </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>     

   <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webview01"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1">
   </WebView>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity

```
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

*Remember add internet permission

Comment: thanks for the reply, but as i sad to Martin, the idea is to open the page in the android browser, no webview